# Mariadb c connector mysql_real_connect fails Error(2002) [HY000] "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

Tags: c, mariadb, connector

Although I have specified port in the mysql_real_connect function, and unix socket name as NULL,  error message indicates it is trying to connect through unix sock default /tmp/mysql.sock.

```
void show_error(MYSQL *mysql)
{
  printf("Error(%d) [%s] \"%s\"", mysql_errno(mysql),
         mysql_sqlstate(mysql),
         mysql_error(mysql));
  mysql_close(mysql);
  exit(-1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  MYSQL *mysql;
  const char *query;
  MYSQL_RES *result;

  mysql= mysql_init(NULL);
  if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql, "localhost", "user", "user_pw",
                          "schema_test", 3306, NULL, 0))
    show_error(mysql);
```

Getting error : Error(2002) [HY000] "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use Host as "localhost", mysql_real_connect is ignoring port, instead trying to connect using  unix sock default /tmp/mysql.sock. [Here](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/blob/2759b87d72926b7c9b5426437a7c8dd15ff57945/libmariadb/mariadb_lib.c#L1413)

So in local machine, if We need to connect using port, we can pass 127.0.0.1 in host parameter to mysql_real_connect function.